# How to utilize existing avro schema for my kafka consumer?

Tags: java, apache-kafka, kafka-consumer-api, avro, confluent-schema-registry

I am using Debezium SQL Server Connector to do change data capture, and the connector automatically generates the schema and registers the schema in schema registry, which means I don't have the avro schema file. In this case, how can I write a consumer reading data with this schema? I have seen a lot of articles using the avro schema file to read the data for consumers, and there will only be one schema for this payload in the schema registry.

If I create an avro file locally and let my consumer use it, then I have to register a duplicate schema with a different name.

My question is how to write a Java consumer API using this schema registered by a kafka connector. Thank you so much.

Here is my value schema:

```
{"subject":"new.dbo.locations-value","version":1,"id":102,"schema":"{\"type\":\"record\",\"name\":\"Envelope\",\"namespace\":\"new.dbo.locations\",\"fields\":[{\"name\":\"before\",\"type\":[\"null\",{\"type\":\"record\",\"name\":\"Value\",\"fields\":[{\"name\":\"id\",\"type\":\"long\"},{\"name\":\"display_id\",\"type\":\"string\"},{\"name\":\"first_name\",\"type\":\"string\"},{\"name\":\"last_name\",\"type\":\"string\"},{\"name\":\"location_id\",\"type\":\"string\"},{\"name\":\"location_name\",\"type\":\"string\"},{\"name\":\"location_sub_type_id\",\"type\":[\"null\",\"string\"],\"default\":null},{\"name\":\"location_time_zone\",\"type\":[\"null\",\"string\"],\"default\":null},{\"name\":\"parent_organization_id\",\"type\":[\"null\",\"string\"],\"default\":null},{\"name\":\"type\",\"type\":[\"null\",\"string\"],\"default\":null}],\"connect.name\":\"new.dbo.locations.Value\"}],\"default\":null},{\"name\":\"after\",\"type\":[\"null\",\"Value\"],\"default\":null},{\"name\":\"source\",\"type\":{\"type\":\"record\",\"name\":\"Source\",\"namespace\":\"io.debezium.connector.sqlserver\",\"fields\":[{\"name\":\"version\",\"type\":\"string\"},{\"name\":\"connector\",\"type\":\"string\"},{\"name\":\"name\",\"type\":\"string\"},{\"name\":\"ts_ms\",\"type\":\"long\"},{\"name\":\"snapshot\",\"type\":[{\"type\":\"string\",\"connect.version\":1,\"connect.parameters\":{\"allowed\":\"true,last,false\"},\"connect.default\":\"false\",\"connect.name\":\"io.debezium.data.Enum\"},\"null\"],\"default\":\"false\"},{\"name\":\"db\",\"type\":\"string\"},{\"name\":\"schema\",\"type\":\"string\"},{\"name\":\"table\",\"type\":\"string\"},{\"name\":\"change_lsn\",\"type\":[\"null\",\"string\"],\"default\":null},{\"name\":\"commit_lsn\",\"type\":[\"null\",\"string\"],\"default\":null},{\"name\":\"event_serial_no\",\"type\":[\"null\",\"long\"],\"default\":null}],\"connect.name\":\"io.debezium.connector.sqlserver.Source\"}},{\"name\":\"op\",\"type\":\"string\"},{\"name\":\"ts_ms\",\"type\":[\"null\",\"long\"],\"default\":null},{\"name\":\"transaction\",\"type\":[\"null\",{\"type\":\"record\",\"name\":\"ConnectDefault\",\"namespace\":\"io.confluent.connect.avro\",\"fields\":[{\"name\":\"id\",\"type\":\"string\"},{\"name\":\"total_order\",\"type\":\"long\"},{\"name\":\"data_collection_order\",\"type\":\"long\"}]}],\"default\":null}],\"connect.name\":\"new.dbo.locations.Envelope\"}"}%
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You don't need a local schema file. You can consume using `KafkaConsumer<?, GenericRecord>`, which will let the deserializer download and cache the respective ID+schema for each message.

Downside of this approach is that you need to be careful about parsing the data (much like raw JSON)

If you need a static schema and the compiled class which will allow for strict type-checking, then download it from the registry at `/subjects/:name/versions/latest`

Comment: Thank you so much! It works for me! Btw, how can I choose the specific version of the schema for my consumer API with KafkaConsumer<?, GenericRecord>?

Comment: If you need a specific version, that is when you do need to use/download a schema file. With this method, it always deserializes to the schema ID version that is embedded in the message (and unfortunately, there is no way to actually detect that version at run-time)

Comment: Thanks for your quick response. Helps a lot!